# Series radius and interval of convergence

Tags: calculus

> Find the radius and interval of convergence for the power series
>
> $$\sum_0^\infty(-1)^n(4x+1)^n$$

I solved until $\lim\left|4x+1\right|$ and got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  test tells us that the series converges if $$1>\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=|4x+1|$$

Hence, we need to know when $|4x+1|=1$ to find the boundary points of the interval.  This breaks down to $4x+1=\pm 1$.  If $4x+1=1$, then $x=0$.  If $4x+1=-1$, then $x=-0.5$.  Hence the series converges on $(-0.5,0)$, diverges on $(-\infty,-0.5)\cup(0,+\infty)$.  From this we can tell that the radius of convergence is half of that length, i.e. $0.25$.

What remains to do is to check the boundary points, which are as of yet unknown.  Plug $x=-0.5$ in, and see if the result converges.  Then plug $x=0$ in, and see if THAT converges.